# Maneiras de usar cURL com PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl, twitter-api

Estou estudando `cURL` para dar continuidade na minha *aplicação*, revisei meu código e monitorei o **network** do Twitter e obtive os seguintes `HTTP Headers`:

```
curl "https://twitter.com/" 

-H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" 
-H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" 
-H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" 
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" 
-H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" 
-H "cache-control: max-age=0" 
-H "authority: twitter.com" 
-H "cookie: (RETIRADO POR SEGURANÇA!) --compressed
```

O meu código está bem simples, mas surgiu a dúvida, há necessidade de fazer as mesmas chamadas?

A baixo meu código simplório:

```
$cookies = [];

$url_twitter = 'https://twitter.com';

$twitter_cookies = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($twitter_cookies, [
        CURLOPT_URL             => $url_twitter,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR               => ROOT . 'system' . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $TwitterUser . '.txt',
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($twitter_cookies, $header) use (&$cookies) {
            if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                if (preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/i', $header, $matches)) {
                    $cookies[] = $matches[1];
                }
            }

            return strlen($header);
        }
    ]
);
```

Como podem ver não implementei nem a metade dos pedidos de *HEADERS* que o Twitter mostrou ao copiar o `cURL` citado no início do tópico.

Não sei se adiciona automaticamente, entendo o básico de `HTTPS`, mas há necessidade de fazer essas chamadas ou é adicionado automaticamente?

```
"accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"

"accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"

"upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"

"user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

"accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"

"cache-control: max-age=0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os cabeçalhos são usados para que ambas as partes possam se entender de maneira geral, elas define o que o cliente suporta ou espera como resultado, entre outras opções, algumas por segurança.

---

O primeiro `accept-encoding` diz qual tipo de compressão cliente suporta. Se você usar um cURL que não tem suporte para isso o sistema vai quebrar, irá aparecer um monte de "caracteres estranhos". O cURL pode definir esses cabeçalhos automaticamente, informando o que ele suporta, desde que defina o `CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING` (antes era o `CURLOPT_ENCODING`) para `""` (string vazia), se definir para nulo (o padrão) ele não vai usar nenhum tipo de compressão.

O `accept-language` e o `upgrade-insecure-requests` são auto explicativos, o primeiro pode ser útil caso o website retorne informações baseadas no idioma, o segundo indica que o cliente prefere que seja redirecionado para o HTTPS caso esteja no HTTP.

O `user-agent` extremamente importante para o cURL, assim ele poderá se passar por um navegador qualquer, *inclusive navegadores mobile*. O cURL tem até o `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` para que você defina o valor desejado, ou pode fazer manualmente, *que geralmente eu faço*.

O `accept` e o `cache-control` define para que não use uma versão salva em cache, porém no cURL isso não é suficiente. Você deve também usar o `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` e o `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` dependendo dos casos para realmente criar uma nova requisição.

O `authority:` (na verdade deve ser `:authority`) é um "[Pseudo-Header](http://undertow.io/blog/2015/04/27/An-in-depth-overview-of-HTTP2.html)" do HTTP/2, equivalente ao `HOST`, é recomendado que seja definido, mas o cURL faz isso automaticamente, *na maior parte das vezes*. Mas, é extremante necessário definir manualmente se for conectar diretamente com um IP, *para evitar DNS-Lookup*.

O `cookie:` são os cookies podem ser usados de diversas maneiras, desde `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` ou `CURLOPT_COOKIE` ou manualmente. *Existe também a opção de usar o `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` para ignorar os cookies de sessão e afins.*

Vários outros cabeçalhos podem existir (como o `referer`, `pragma`, `origin`, `dnt` além de coisas como `content-type` e `content-length` que são definidas automaticamente quando necessário).

Mas, ainda é possível criar um cabeçalho personalizado (geralmente iniciados em `x-`), no caso o próprio Twitter usa alguns como o `x-csrf-token`.

---

*Qualquer cabeçalho pode ser definido no cURL usando o `-H` ou o `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, sem necessidade de usar qualquer outra função para isso.*

Comment: Era esta a resposta esperada, @Inkeliz, você é de mais, +1

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente as requisições HTTP são realizadas via browser, que naturalmente fornece diversos HTTP Headers dentro da request.

O **uso** da palavra **necessidade** é complicado, pois isso depende mais do lado da aplicação a ser requisitada do que daquilo que você esta mandando. 
É necessário estudar a aplicação e compreender os tipos de parametros que ela aceita.

Digamos que você possa enviar qualquer informação dentro do header do curl, como `teste=123`, e o retorno da aplicação pode variar, como uma exception de argumentos adicionais ou mesmo pode ser que a aplicação ignore isso.

Comment: Paulo, não sei se é a resposta ou se é eu, mas não entendi. (?) perdão.

Comment: É necessario estudar o sistema que receberá o request para saber se é necessário informar todos os parametros ou não.

Comment: Sim, desculpe minha ignorância, mas quais são estes estudos?

Comment: Você vai enviar um post para algum endpoint do twitter né? Então vai ser necessário que procure na documentação do twitter alguma maneira de realizar essa integração com o seu sistema. Dê uma olhada em: https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: Sim, enviarei sem uso de API. vou marcar sua resposta como resolvido. obrigado.

Comment: Bom, nesse caso não tem muito como descobrir os campos necessários :/, var ter que ser no chute.